# How to kill / reload / autoreload a django server having persistent connections like SSE ?

Tags: python, django, persistent-connection

`django-admin.py runserver` is running while developing. I have an open webpage connected to my sse endpoint.

Seems like using `django-sse` breaks to server autoreload feature, cf. this [issue](https://github.com/niwibe/django-sse/issues/8).

What's worse is that if I manually restart the server (`Ctr+C` & `django-admin.py runserver`), it fails with a 'port already in use error' and I need to `ps` `grep runserver` `kill whatever_id` first, a true PITA.

So:

- How comes using persistent connections breaks my dev workflow ?
- Is there an easy workaround not involving patching django ?

In production I'm using a Procfile with foreman to launch gunicorn gevent workers. Here a manual restart goes fine (open connections are closed) but there's not autoreload feature nor any log printed in the terminal.